# Elixir Phoenix - uploading multiple images with Task module

Tags: asynchronous, elixir, phoenix-framework

This is my first Elixir/Phoenix project and I am loving it so far. Sadly, I haven't had much time to really explore tasks/concurrency or otp.

I have a form that can allow up to 7 image uploads in one go. I initially set up the code to upload these synchronously, 1 by 1. My next iteration was to attempt to run these in parallel, which can be seen in the `upload_many` function below.

The total time taken to upload 7 x 250kb images has not reduced (~15 seconds) with my re-write which clearly suggests I am doing something wrong.

I would really appreciate any assistance or advice.

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.S3 do
  def upload_many(params, keys) do
    ops = [max_concurrency: System.schedulers_online() * 3, timeout: 20000]

    keys
    # [{"passport_image_url", file}, {"drivers_license_url", file2}, ...]
    |> Task.async_stream(&upload/1, ops)
    |> Enum.to_list()
  end

  def upload({url_key, image_params}) do
    unique_filename = get_unique_filename(image_params.filename)

    case File.read(image_params.path) do
      {:error, _} ->
        {:error, url_key, "file could not be read"}
      {:ok, image_binary} ->
        # returns image url string or error
        res = put_object(unique_filename, image_binary)
        IO.inspect url_key
        Tuple.insert_at(res, 1, url_key)
        # {:ok, url_key, url}
    end
  end


  def get_unique_filename(filename) do
    file_uuid = UUID.uuid4(:hex)
    image_filename = filename
    "#{file_uuid}-#{image_filename}"
  end


  def put_object(unique, image_binary) do
    bucket = System.get_env("BUCKET_NAME")

    res = ExAws.S3.put_object(bucket, unique, image_binary)
    |> ExAws.request!

    case res do
      %{status_code: 200} ->
        {:ok, image_url(unique, bucket)}
      _ ->
        {:error, "error uploading to S3"}
    end
  end

  def image_url(unique, bucket) do
    "https://#{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/#{bucket}/#{unique}"
  end
end
```

I have written a test that uploads 7 images and has run it with and without mocking the `ExAws` request with `Process.sleep(4000); %{status_code: 200}`.  With a 4 second mock, it manages to perform 7 tasks simultaneously in just over 4 seconds, but if I remove the mock and upload the files for real, it takes around 15 seconds again. Here is the test:

```elixir
  test "updates startpack with many file uploads", %{conn: conn, user: user} do
    startpack = Repo.insert! %Startpack{user_id: user.id}
    image_upload = %Plug.Upload{path: "test/fixtures/foxy.png", filename: "foxy.png"}

    # possible solution for multiple fields
    images = %{
     "passport_image"  => image_upload,
     "vehicle_insurance_image"  => image_upload,
     "box_rental_image"  => image_upload,
     "equipment_rental_image"  => image_upload,
     "p45_image"  => image_upload,
     "schedule_d_letter_image"  => image_upload,
     "loan_out_company_cert_image"  => image_upload
   }

    valid = Map.merge(@valid_attrs, images)

    with_mock ExAws, [request!: fn(_) ->
      Process.sleep(4000)
      %{status_code: 200}
    end] do
      conn = put conn, startpack_path(conn, :update, startpack), startpack: valid
      assert redirected_to(conn) == startpack_path(conn, :show, startpack)
      startpack = Repo.get_by(Startpack, user_id: user.id)
      assert startpack.passport_url
    end
  end
```

Comment: After doing some research, I am starting to wonder if I am simply maxing out the upload capabilities (bandwidth?) and the code is actually fine. 15-18 seconds seems like a long time to upload 7 small images so I'm not sure.  If this is the case, is there any benefit of running the uploads concurrently? I read somewhere that you would start to see the benefits when running multiple threads.. I am not sure if that applies here.

Comment: It's worth noting that I have deployed and manually tested on Heroku and still get similar times posted above.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ExAws` but it seems like it's using `:hackney` underneath. Hackney has a concept of connection pools. Maybe you could see how ExAws sets hackney up and try to tamper with the pool settings? Eg. try turning it off or increasing connection count.

Comment: Thanks @bottlenecked, i'll try to take a look. Do you think the bottlenecking is something that I am using other than something out of my control eg, internet connection. ??

Comment: Sure, this could be the case. To test this theory (that your line is saturated) you can try either 1) deploying your code on heroku and uploading to aws (which should be fast if internet connection is the problem) or 2) use your previous language and write a solution with the same semantics (ie parallel upload), which should behave the same (15 secs to finish)

Comment: I have deployed and manual tested with no improvement. Today I found the following function on ExAws https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws/ExAws.S3.html#upload/4 which may be designed to upload more than 1 image at one time?

Comment: If I read the docs correctly then this method will parallelize the parts within a single file, not multiple files. Could it be some kind of rate-limiting on your aws account? I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code.